# Can't see my database in the SQL Server Object Explorer but database is working

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

I'm creating a basic database with entity:

```
namespace EntityFrameworkSamples
{
    public class Kategori
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string KategoriAdi { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Category.cs

```
namespace EntityFrameworkSamples
{
    public class UrunContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Kategori> Kategoriler { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Urun> Urunler { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my context

also my Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace EntityFrameworkSamples
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Kategori k = new Kategori();
            k.KategoriAdi = "bilgisayaadsr";

            UrunContext db = new UrunContext();
            db.Kategoriler.Add(k);
            db.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("veri kayit edildi");

            var kategoriler = db.Kategoriler.ToList();
            foreach (var kategori in kategoriler)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(kategori.KategoriAdi);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but I can't see my database in the SQL Server Object Explorer or SQL Server Management Studio.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: SQL Server Object Explorer]

[image: OUTPUT]

Thank you. Have a great day..

**UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="v11.0" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Quest is updated with `app.config`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First can't find database in server explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655565/entity-framework-code-first-cant-find-database-in-server-explorer)

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the object explorer by right-clicking the server name and selecting refresh?

Comment: its not our app.config files not same i tried the answers but its still not showing. Im updating the question with my app.config @esiprogrammer

Comment: yes i tried @Zorkolot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I found the solution.

first i added connection string in my app.config
there is connection string :

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="urunConnection" 
         connectionString="server=DESKTOP-RV5GVB8;database=urunDb;integrated security=true;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

then i added a constructer in my Context with my connection string name..

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace entityFreamworkSamples
{
    public class UrunContext:DbContext
    {
        public UrunContext(): base("urunConnection")// here it is
        {

        }


        public DbSet<Kategori> Kategoriler { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Urun> Urunler { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and problem is fixed. Now i can see my Database Sql Server Object Explorer and Sql Server menagement studio.